# Set the data in React Context from asynchronous API call

Tags: reactjs, rest, asynchronous, synchronization

I am trying to initialize a custom React context with data from back end, using a GET API request. However, the context is loaded before the API call finishe the data fetching.

What I've tried is to use a consumer to send data to the child component but I can only access the default value of the context which is set then the context is created.

Here is how I am trying to set my context data

```
import React, {useState,useEffect} from "react";
import {callAffiliateApi} from "./services/affiliateService/transactionContext";

export const AffiliateContext = React.createContext("Raaaaaaaaaaaa");

export const AffiliateProvider  = ({children}) => {

  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  useEffect(()=> {
    async function fetchData() {
      const newText = await callAffiliateApi();
      setData(newText)
    };fetchData()
  },[])

  console.log("Data in the context", data);
  if(data != null){
    return (
      <AffiliateContext.Provider value={data}>
        {children}
      </AffiliateContext.Provider>
    )}
  else {
    return (
      <AffiliateContext.Provider value={"Loading..."}>
        {children}
      </AffiliateContext.Provider>)
  }

}
```

And here is how I'm trying to access it in the child component

```
import {AffiliateContext} from "../../../../AffiliateContext";

class Profile extends Component {


  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      text: this.props.text,
      user: this.props.user,

    }

  }

  render() {
    return (
    <AffiliateContext.Consumer>
      {data =>
        <div>
        {data}
      </div>}
    </AffiliateContext.Consumer>
      )
  }
}
export default Profile;
```

However, the only thing that gets displayed in the page is "Raaaaaaa", the default value of the component. How can I make the child component wait until the data finishes fetching from the API request?

Comment: Did you used AffiliateProvider  in your index.js or app.js?

Comment: None of them. I just want to access the context in this class.

Comment: You need to do this.

Comment: You are exporting your AffiliateProvider  component, so you need to use it in somewhere before you access in any child components. 
For example you need to wrap jsx in your App.js with AffiliateProvider.
Something like
`
  render() {
    return (
        <AffiliateProvider>
            <div>
                Content of your jsx
            </div>
        </AffiliateProvider>
    );
}
`

Comment: Can't I just add access it in the render of my Child component?

Comment: I dont think you can access, can you try my suggestion?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

try to use `useContext` its cleaner and try not to use the async inside the useEffect!

[their related issues](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14326)

```js
import React, { useState,useEffect,useContext } from "react";
import { callAffiliateApi } from "./services/affiliateService/transactionContext";

const Context = React.createContext({});
const AffiliateContext = init => useContext(Context);

export const AffiliateProvider  = ({children}) => {

  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const [loading,setLoading]=useState(false);

  const getAffiliates = async ()=>{
    setLoading(true)
    const newText = await callAffiliateApi();
    setData(newText)
    setLoading(false)
  }

  useEffect(()=> {
    getAffiliates()
  },[])


    return (
      <AffiliateContext.Provider value={{loading,list:data}}>
        {children}
      </AffiliateContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

Comment: There is no such thing as `useReactContext`.... did you mean `useContext`?

Comment: I believe it was a simple mis-spell of React.useContext()

Comment: The async function originally created in useEffect was perfectly ok.  Using it outside like this requires it be wrapped in `useCallback`.

Comment: I am curious about the `init => useContext(Context);` part someone knows why is it necessary? Normally it would be written  like this: `const AffiliateContext = React.createContext({});`

Comment: please define getAffiliates fn inside the useEffect callback or wrap it in a useCallback hook otherwise this may introduce bugs.