# Probably Async/Wait issue with React Context API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

My **goal** was to make invalid token a global state, so I can render the sell page if jwt token is valid; if not redirect the user to login page. However, the isValidToken function returns undefined, which is probably due to it not being async function. However, if I make it an async function, I get an error. Also, is there any better and concise way to achieve the **goal**.

**This code returns undefined**

**index.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link} from 'react-router-dom'
import { PrivateRoute } from './auth';

//includes
// Bootstrap core CSS
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

//custom css for the page.
import './assets/css/style.css'

// custom fonts for the page.




//import * as Pages from './components';

//components

import Header from './components/headerComponent/header'
import Footer from './components/footerComponent/footer'
import {Homepage, SignIn, SignUp, Dashboard, Sell} from './components/pages'
import {UsersContextProvider} from './contexts'

ReactDOM.render(
<Router>
  <div className="App">
  <UsersContextProvider>
    <Header />
    <div className="content">
       <Route exact path='/' component={Homepage} />
       <PrivateRoute exact path = '/dashboard' component={Dashboard} />
       <Route exact path='/signin' component={SignIn} />
       <Route exact path='/signup' component={SignUp} />
       <Route exact path='/sell' component={Sell} />
    </div>
    <Footer />
  </UsersContextProvider>
  </div>
  </Router>,

  document.getElementById('root'));
```

**sell.js**

```
import React, { Component, useContext } from 'react';
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

import '../../assets/css/sell.css';

// import {isLoggedIn} from '../../auth';

import API from '../../api';
import  { UsersContext } from "../../contexts";

const Sell = (props) => {

  //get the usersContext
  const { isUserSignedIn, isValidToken, checkToken } = useContext(UsersContext);

  return (
    <div>
      {checkToken()}
      {console.log(checkToken())}
      {console.log(isUserSignedIn)}
      {console.log(isValidToken)}
      <h4>User Details: {isUserSignedIn}</h4>
      
    </div>)
}

export default Sell;
```

**auth.js**

```
export function isValidToken () {
  let token = localStorage.getItem("jwt_token");
  if(token == null){
    return false
  } else{
    API.get('/users/user_detail', {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
      }
    }).then(res =>  {
      console.log("valid token");
      return res
    }).catch(err => {
      return false
    })
  }
}
```

**context.js**

```
// import {isValidToken} from './auth';


// // User context
// const UserContext = React.createContext();

// export default class UserProvider extends Component {
//   state = {
//     isLoggedIn : false,
//     isValidToken : false
//   }

//   render() {
//     return (
//       <UserContext.Provider value={{
//         state: this.state,
//         isValidToken: isValidToken
//       }}>
//         {this.props.children}
//       </UserContext.Provider>
//     )
//   }
// }



import React, { createContext, useState } from "react";
import { isValidToken as isValidTokenFunc }from '../auth';
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

export const Context = createContext({});

export const Provider = props => {
  // Initial values are obtained from the props
  const {
    isUserSignedIn: initialIsUserSignedIn,
    isValidToken: initialIsValidToken,
    children
  } = props;

  // Use State to keep the values
  const [isUserSignedIn, setIsUserSignedIn] = useState(initialIsUserSignedIn);
  const [isValidToken, setIsValidToken] = useState(initialIsValidToken);

  const checkToken = () => {
    setIsValidToken(isValidTokenFunc())
  }

  // Make the context object:
  const usersContext = {
    isUserSignedIn,
    setIsUserSignedIn,
    isValidToken,
    setIsValidToken,
    checkToken
  };

  // pass the value in provider and return
  return <Context.Provider value={usersContext}>{children}</Context.Provider>;
};

export const { Consumer } = Context;

Provider.propTypes = {
  users: PropTypes.bool,
  selectedUser: PropTypes.bool
};

Provider.defaultProps = {
  isUserSignedIn: false,
  isValidToken: false
};`
```

**This code return error, trying to make the isValidToken async**

**contexts.js**

```
// import React, { Component } from 'react';

// import {isValidToken} from './auth';


// // User context
// const UserContext = React.createContext();

// export default class UserProvider extends Component {
//   state = {
//     isLoggedIn : false,
//     isValidToken : false
//   }

//   render() {
//     return (
//       <UserContext.Provider value={{
//         state: this.state,
//         isValidToken: isValidToken
//       }}>
//         {this.props.children}
//       </UserContext.Provider>
//     )
//   }
// }



import React, { createContext, useState } from "react";
import { isValidToken as isValidTokenFunc }from '../auth';
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

export const Context = createContext({});

export const Provider = props => {
  // Initial values are obtained from the props
  const {
    isUserSignedIn: initialIsUserSignedIn,
    isValidToken: initialIsValidToken,
    children
  } = props;

  // Use State to keep the values
  const [isUserSignedIn, setIsUserSignedIn] = useState(initialIsUserSignedIn);
  const [isValidToken, setIsValidToken] = useState(initialIsValidToken);

  const checkToken = async () => {
    setIsValidToken(await isValidTokenFunc())
  }

  // Make the context object:
  const usersContext = {
    isUserSignedIn,
    setIsUserSignedIn,
    isValidToken,
    setIsValidToken,
    checkToken
  };

  // pass the value in provider and return
  return <Context.Provider value={usersContext}>{children}</Context.Provider>;
};

export const { Consumer } = Context;

Provider.propTypes = {
  users: PropTypes.bool,
  selectedUser: PropTypes.bool
};

Provider.defaultProps = {
  isUserSignedIn: false,
  isValidToken: false
};
```

[image]

Comment: This might be a case for `useEffect`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58198369/5243272

Comment: You are not returning the result from the api call on the auth.js file,  just add `return` before `Api.get`

Comment: adding return infront of API.get will give me crash the program due to an unlimited loop into god knows what

Comment: Inside `Sell` component you are trying to return a bunch of functions. Move them inside an effect as suggested in the first comment.

Comment: hey Fedrico, that really worked. So I moved checkToken() inside useEffect(), and added return infront of API.get(). Thanks! :)