# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'AnimeCategory')

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, axios, use-effect

im trying to get "AnimeCategory" from this code i named 'Context.js'

```
import axios from "axios";
import React, { createContext, useState } from "react";

export const AnimeContext = createContext();

const Context = ({ children }) => {
    const [index, setIndex] = useState(1);
    const [error, setError] = useState('');

    const AnimeCategory = async (id) => {
        const { data } = await axios.get(`https://api.jikan.moe/v3/genre/anime/${id}/1`);
        setIndex(1);
        return data;
    };

    return (
        <AnimeContext.Provider
            value={{
                index,
                setIndex,
                AnimeCategory,
                error,
                setError,
            }}
        >
            {children}
        </AnimeContext.Provider>
    );
};

export default Context;
```

but after i call it using below code in another file

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from 'react'
import { AnimeContext } from "../API/Context";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, SafeAreaView, TouchableOpacity, Image, ScrollView, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';

const Kategori = ({id}) => {
  const { AnimeCategory, setError } = useContext(AnimeContext);
  const [Loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
  const [GenreName, setGenreName] = useState('')
  const [GenreList, setGenreList] = useState([])
```

it giving error 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'AnimeCategory')'

how can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use first answer from this: [Set the data in React Context from asynchronous API call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58197800/set-the-data-in-react-context-from-asynchronous-api-call)

You do not wait until you receive data from your api call.